# Anagram Checker Explanation

Tags: anagram

im a first year programmer and i was wondering what this code extract does. Its part of a main which does a check to see if 2 words are anagrams of one another. Im not fullly sure what this represents though.

```
    for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
    {
        if(x == array.length-1)
        {
            array[x] = word1.substring(x);
        }
        else
        {
            array[x] = word1.substring(x, x+1);
        }
    }       
    for(int x = 0; x < array.length && isAnagram != false; x++)
    {
        aLetter = array[x];
        if(word2.indexOf(aLetter) != -1)
        {
            isAnagram = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isAnagram = false;
        }
        if(isAnagram == true)
        {
            word2 = word2.replaceFirst(aLetter, "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: Substring (x) and substirng (x,x+1) really! Dont know too much about whats going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Loop 1:**

Make array of letters in `word1`.

**Loop 2:**

Remove each letter from `word2`.
`isAnagram` starts true.
If any letter is not found then `isAnagram` is false.

At the end `isAnagram` should be true and `word2` should be empty.